# Can I add Card Details without charging the customer with Stripe?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I need my customers to add their credit card info, but I don't want to charge them right away. Is there any way, I can add their details to charge later when using Stripes checkout solution and just store their card token first?

I am using Laravel Cashier on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a Stripe card token. You have two options to do so:

- On the client side (recommended) using Stripe.js & Elements, you first create a card Element ([The Elements object](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#the-elements-object)) and then you create a Stripe card Token ([stripe.createToken()](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token))
- On the server side ([Create a card token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=php)). The easiest way is to install the official Stripe PHP library with `composer require stripe/stripe-php` and then use the following piece of code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("{your_stripe_api_key}");

\Stripe\Token::create([
  "card" => [
    "number" => "{card_number}",
    "exp_month" => {card_expiration_month},
    "exp_year" => {card_expiration_year},
    "cvc" => "{card_security_code}"
  ]
]);
```

Once you have that token you can use Laravel Cashier to store the Stripe card token in database and update the card information in Stripe with the following methods:

```
$user->updateCard($token);
$user->updateCardFromStripe();
```

More information on those methods in the [Updating Credit Cards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/billing#updating-credit-cards) section of the Laravel Cashier documentation.

Comment: You're welcome I am glad I could help. Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: can you please look at this question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335880/how-to-check-if-file-exist-in-external-server-in-laravel

Answer (score -1):

If, like me, you're looking for getting the token :

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("{your_stripe_api_key}");

$token = \Stripe\Token::create([
  "card" => [
    "number" => "{card_number}",
    "exp_month" => {card_expiration_month},
    "exp_year" => {card_expiration_year},
    "cvc" => "{card_security_code}"
  ]
]);

$user->updateCard($token->id);
$user->updateCardFromStripe();
```

Thanks @louisfischer