# How to check if file exist in external server in laravel?

Tags: laravel, ftp, filesystems

I have two different server. In first server laravel application is deployed and in second server some files are stored. I want to check if a specific file exists in second server from laravel application. I have ftp credentials of second server. I am using laravel filesystem to connect second server. I have defined ftp credentials in config/filesystem.php file. Below is the code what I have tried

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->exists('generated/file1.csv');
```

I am getting following error:

```
ftp_chdir(): Can't change directory to /home/username/public_html/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure you've set the root directory correctly. It seems to be pointed to one that doesn't exist. I think the option is `'root' => '/absolute/path/to/ftp/root/'`

Comment: I have defined option in config/filesystem.php file

        'ftp' => [
                'driver' => 'ftp',
                'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
                'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
                'root' => 'home/user/public_html'
            ],